# Why is an Artificial Neural Network with high accuracy score giving poor results?

Tags: neural-networks

I implemented my ANN using SKlearn module's class MLPClassifier. Fitting it on some data and testing it on a very specific subset of said training data, it gives a score of 1.0, but actually using the ANN to **generate outputs for said testing data** almost always gives incorrect output. What could be the possible reasons for this?
I am using this ANN as a memory network and there is never a case when input is out of training data.

Comment: Overfitting overfitting overfitting!

Comment: My [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16558/when-is-a-neural-networked-considered-to-be-overfitted) on a similar question might help you.

Answer (score 3):

You're testing your neural net with data from the training set, of course it will get you great results. But you're neural net is now trained for a specific data and is unable to make generalization. This is known as Overfitting.

You should either split your data into test/train or use another technique to estimate your NN performance. A good technique is K-fold Cross validation.

Also check [Overfitting wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) and [Cross validation on sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) if you want more details.